# How to set property whose values are in list in c# .net core

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list which holds 3 values, for example

```
"Elon"
"1221342"
"Benguluru"
```

I have a class named Elements which has 3 properties

```cs
public class Elements
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

List<string> val = new List<string>();
```

I am looping through another list and saving the values in list `val`

```cs
foreach (var elemTd in lstTdElem)
{
    val.Add(elemTd.Text);                        
}
```

Now this list `val` has all these three values mentioned above.

I want to set the value of list `val` in each property one by one.

so,
`Name` should be "Dominos"
`Id` should be "1221342"
`City` should be "Benguluru"

I am a newbie. Request you to please help.

Comment: Should name be Dominos or Elon? In any case you need [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)

Comment: It should be Elon. and I already tried the reflection but same value is getting set in all the properties.

Comment: `var instance = new Elements() { Name = val[0], Id = val[1], City = val[2] };` is the safest and fastest way to do it, so long as you check that `val` contains 3 items first. By the way, it seems like `Elements` is a bad name for a singular item. To me, `Elements` suggests that it's a collection object.

Comment: @vc74 Reflection would not help, `elemId != Id`

Comment: It should be Elon. and I already tried the reflection but same value is getting set in all the properties.   Elements model = new Elementsl();                      foreach (string str in val)
                    {                  


                        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ElementModel).GetProperties();
                        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                        {
                            property.SetValue(model, str);

                        }

                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood (clarify if I am wrong)

You have a list of Name, Id, and city in a list and you want to make an instance of class `Elements` from the values in the list.

List is like

```
"Elon",
"1221342",
"Benguluru"
```

If that is the case:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Elements).GetProperties();
Elements model = new Elements();
foreach (var elemTd in lstTdElem)
{
    val.Add(elemTd);
}
for (int n = 0; n < properties.Length; n++)
{
    var property = properties[n];

    property.SetValue(model, val[n]);
}
```

This code will set `Elements` properties according to the list

```
Console.WriteLine(model.Name);  // Elon
Console.WriteLine(model.Id);    // 1221342
Console.WriteLine(model.City);  // Benguluru
```